# HTML Quotes are making a mess

Tags: javascript, php, html

The result I want:

```
<div class="cat_cards_item" onclick="myFunction('http://website','name','description')">
```

I tried 2 methods:

1.

```
echo "<div class='cat_cards_item' onclick='myFunction(" . $resultwebsite['website'] . "," . $resultname['name'] . "," . $resultdesc['description'] . ")'>"
```

My result:

````
<div class="cat_cards_item" onclick="myFunction(http://website,name,description)">```
````

2. 

```
echo "<div class='cat_cards_item' onclick='myFunction('" . $resultwebsite['website'] . "','" . $resultname['name'] . "','" . $resultdesc['description'] . "')'>"
```

My result:

```
<div class="cat_cards_item" onclick="myFunction(" http:="" website="" ',' name="" ',' description=""')'="">
```

Im trying to call a javascript function that opens a modal with the information I pull from my php code.
I tried most styles of placing quotes and im getting a headache from it, any help?

Comment: use a backslash to escape the double quotes ~ ie: `echo "<div class='cat_cards_item' onclick='myFunction(\"$resultwebsite['website']\",\"$resultdesc['description']\");`

Comment: heredoc, and for that context: json_encode(), htmlentities() (`&quot;`).

Answer (score 3):

By using the heredoc-syntax you can get a more readable string, and you can simply integrate your variables without concatenations:

```
<?php
$mydiv = <<<EOD
   <div class="cat_cards_item" onclick="myFunction('{$resultwebsite['website']}','{$resultname['name']}','{$resultdesc['description']}')">
EOD;
echo $mydiv;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would create multiple of the same HTML-structure, I would create a simple PHP function that generates the HTML code, so you don't have to worry about the quotes:

```php
<?php

    $HTML = createModal('cat_cards_item', "myFunction('http://website','name','description')");
    echo $HTML;
    
    function createModal($class, $onClick) {
        return "<div class=\"${class}\" onclick=\"${onClick}\">";
    }
```

> `<div class="cat_cards_item" onclick="myFunction('http://website','name','description')">`

[Try the PHP code online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4d319251990a1d4dd4948f123331d4728e9d37e)